# XPath, in a Greasemonkey script, is not selecting right nodes on an XHTML page

Tags: javascript, xpath, xhtml, greasemonkey, weibo

I'm working on a Greasemonkey script for *weibo.com*. I can't pick the elements using XPath on the XHTML page.

This code fails to grab the elements I want:

```
function resolver(prefix) {
    return prefix === 'x' ? 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' : null;
}
var allLinks, thisLink;
allLinks = document.evaluate(
  "//x:a[@href]", 
  document, 
  resolver, 
  XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
  null 
);
```

Only the `<a>` elements on the sidebar are picked and the rest are still there. Please refer to [this, weibo.com, target page](http://s.weibo.com/weibo/IBM&Refer=STopic_box).

Is there anyway to pick all the elements with attribute `action-type="login"`?

I used `"//x:a[@action-type='login']"`, but It didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the script is running before all of these nodes are added to the page.  They are added by the page's AJAX later.

So, you could add a time-delay to your script. **But:**

1. If you just want to grab select elements, you almost never need to use XPath.  Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)  or jQuery instead. Here's a basic example with `querySelectorAll` and no time delay:

   ```js
   var allLinks = document.querySelectorAll ("a[action-type='login']");
   if (allLinks.length) {
       // PROCESS NODES AS DESIRED, HERE.
   }
   ```
2. Here's a **complete Greasemonkey script**, that handles the delayed content problem using jQuery and [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891):

   ```js
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name        _Weibo, hilite login links
   // @include     http://s.weibo.com/weibo/*
   // @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
   // @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
   // @grant    GM_addStyle
   // ==/UserScript==
   /*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
       introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
   */

   function processLoginLinks (jNode) {
       //***** YOUR CODE HERE *****
       jNode.css ("background", "lime");
   }

   waitForKeyElements ("a[action-type='login']", processLoginLinks);
   ```

Comment: If you don't log into weibo, the page will be different, all you get is elements with [code]action-type="login"[/code]

Comment: Actually, I got `action-type`s of: 
`feed_list_item`, `feed_list_media_img`, `feed_list_url`, `hover`, `login`, `remove` and `searchItem`. ... Anyway, most of us don't have and won't get a login to that site.  If the logged-in page is required, save a complete snapshot of the (X)HTML to http://pastebin.com/ and link to that. ... Irregardless, my answer should work anyway, especially the second half.

Comment: Hi, Brock, thanks for your kindly help, I still cannot fetch the elements, but the hint of "delayed content" quite helps, would you plz tell how to get elements in delayed content? I've read your recommmend page and I don't know how to make that using waitForKeyElements

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer, but it did not work. After checking the target page source code, I find the content are generated dynamically by script, maybe it's why I can't fetch the right elements. You can refer the target page source code here, http://www.dennispot.com/dynamic_search_result.txt, what can I do with this kind of issue?

Comment: **How** did it "not work"?  What error messages did you get on Firefox's error console? Did you install the userscript I posted (item 2)?  I tested it and it appeared to work perfectly -- at least on that one test page.

Comment: Find a "invalid label" error from The error console, and I rename this script (just remove the comma), and It works perfectly. Big Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks to you, Brock~