# How do I use Greasemonkey to hide an XPath element?

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have an XPath `/html/body/div[1]/div/div/center[1]/table` and I would like to make it so it is no longer visible.

I saw I could use `document.evaluate()` but I am not sure how to hide it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you insist on using XPath, for a single node, **use `FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE`** like so:

```
var targEval = document.evaluate (
    "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/center[1]/table",
    document.documentElement,
    null,
    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
    null
);
if (targEval  &&  targEval.singleNodeValue) {
    var targNode  = targEval.singleNodeValue;

    // Payload code starts here.
    targNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

---

But, XPath selectors are very brittle in userscripts.  You're better off [using a CSS selector in most cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508)
Since the HTML wasn't provided, here is **the CSS-selector method** shown with a translation of that XPath into a CSS selector:

```
var targNode = document.querySelector ("body > div:nth-of-type(1) > div > div > center:nth-of-type(1) > table");
if (targNode) {
    targNode.style.display = "none";
}
```

---

Of course, it's even simpler **with jQuery**:

```
$("body > div:first > div > div > center:first > table").hide ();
```

or possibly:

```
$("body > div:first > div > div > center:first > table").first ().hide ();
```

---

If the node is added via AJAX, use a technique such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13064357/331508).